# FDT won't install on Win 64

Tags: installation, fdt

I have purchased 1 month subscription to FDT to try it out, but there is no installation on Windows. I know it is supposed to run from exe, but it won't let me, even though I have verified I have the latest version [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/supeT.png)

**Java error**

[image]

**Latest Version**

[image]

Please help - it cost money and is very frustrating!!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am running 64bit Windows 7, The java error above looks like it is reading the OS as 32bit.  So, following the advice in eclipse forums regarding bittedness:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/

So I downloaded the 32-bit version of FDT, and it solved the problem!

Cheers.